# SPARK : getting file does not exist Error after using addFile functionality

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to write a simple program using `addFile` Function but I'm getting an error in my worker node, that the file doest not exist

```
Stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, slave2.novalocal): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
file:/tmp/spark-2791415c-8c20-4920-b3cd-5a6b8b6f3f8d/userFiles-a5a98f06-2d38-4876-8c8c-82a10ac5431f/csv_ip.csv does not exist
```

Code is as below :

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val inputFile ="file:///home/ubuntu/test/Spark_CSV/spark_csv_job/csv_ip.csv"
sc.addFile(inputFile)
val inFile = sc.textFile("file://"+SparkFiles.get("csv_ip.csv"))
inFile.take(10).foreach(println)
```

please help me resolve error. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try dumping the file onto HDFS and `sc.addFile("hdfs:<filepath_on_hdfs>/csv_ip.csv")`